# Why does the page take so much time to Load ? Its in waiting status?

Tags: php, html, http-headers, webserver

I have this website  which I designed , It takes a lot of time to load the Page. The Chrome Console shows its in Waiting state , What is that and how can I fix it ?

[image: So much time to Load the page]

Comment: Got a URL? Can't help much without one. Seeing the code would also be a big help.

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps you should add that to your question. Now all we need is the php code. We can probably find the problem if you show us.

Comment: use `microtime(true)` in between php code to debug which step is taking this long in the execution.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs - Updated the Code , Please have a look

Comment: @SreenathSoman - I should Add the `microtime(true)` in between the PHP code present everywhere on the page ? 

Do  I have to use `echo ` also with it ?

Comment: You can use `header("Location: login.php');` to redirect the user instead of outputting javascript.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the FB code? Just to see if it takes a long time too. Also, you should consider moving all JS code to the bottom.

Comment: sure `echo` too ofcourse

Comment: @SreenathSoman - 

I added that  all of them are nearly the same value.

But I also go this `Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/earnfame/public_html/view.php:2) in /home/earnfame/public_html/view.php on line 3
`

Comment: its appearing faster now. must've been that FB API call that was slow. did you remove it ?

Comment: @SreenathSoman -I moved the JS to the bottom ,and removed the graphs.facebook URL .  But still its taking the waiting time as 15 sec as showing the image above . :/

Comment: ok now looking at it the jquery js files are taking the time. can you try loading those js files from some third party servers like googleapis

Answer (score 3):

I think it might be the call to the facebook graph api which takes some time...

Comment: I suspect the same. I'm not even sure if he needs to check for the token on every page load.

Comment: ` if(!isset($_SESSION['access_token']))` You are talking about this line right ?  

I removed it , still not much progress @rlcabral & @rlcabral

Comment: @rlcabral - Could it be because of `Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/earnfame/public_html/view.php:2) in /home/earnfame/public_html/view.php on line 3
`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that all that JavaScript is slowing down the page. Right now, after you have removed the token check, the HTML loads fine, but the page still loading for a long time until it finally gets all it needs to finish building the page.

**Solution**

- #1 Move the JS to the bottom of the page.
- #2 If you really need all those asynchronous content, try to load offline as much as you can. Cache it if you can.

Comment: @rlcabral- I moved the JS to the bottom , But still its taking the waiting time as 15 sec as showing the image above . :/